# Using Foreach for website. I want a hit counter using PHP & MSQL

Tags: php, counter, hit, hitcounter

So I'm creating a piano library website for my younger cousin.

Currently I use the foreach function to display all the data from my database. Now, this works great and I managed to get a few features working, but one I'm having trouble with is a **"counter".**

Super easy concept, except the fact that I'd like a counter for every single entry.

By **"counter"** I mean that after clicking a link, it would add a +1 to the count. So that each link would have **"Visited 100 times" or "Visited 34 times", etc**.

I have tried the following:

```
if($mysqli){

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM testtable ".$orderbyfilter);
    $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr id='entry'><td>";
        echo ucwords($row['name']);
        echo "</td><td align='center'>";
        echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">url</a>';
        echo "add hit:";
        echo "<a href='?action=callfunction'>Click</a>";


        //current counter script

        if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'callfunction'){
            $hitcount = $row['hitcount'] + 1;
            $id = $row['id'];

            // why doesn't this work?
            $sql="UPDATE testtable SET hitcount='$hitcount' WHERE id='".$id."'"; 
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
        }

        echo "</td><td align='center'>";
        echo $row['level'];
        echo "</td><td align='center'>";
        echo $row['hitcount'];
        echo "</td></tr>";

    }

        mysqli_close($mysqli);

    } else {
        echo "table did not correctly display!";
}
```

Obviously the method:

```
$sql="UPDATE testtable SET hitcount='$hitcount' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

Doesn't work, as when I click the link, it updates all entries with the same hit count. However when I change it to:

```
$sql="UPDATE testtable SET hitcount='$hitcount' WHERE id='2'";
```

It works perfectly, where it only modifies hitcount for the row with `id=2`.

Obviously the problem has to do with the **`"foreach"`** and setting `$row[id]` as a variable, but honestly I could use some help.

Does it have something to do with variable of variables? I have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col_x = col_x +1 WHERE col_y = 'xyz'` - the problem is that it's in your loop, why use one in the first place?

Comment: Hi Fred,

I understand that I need to use that string to get what I want. The problem I am having is the "WHERE" part.

I need it so that the "WHERE" is automatically modified to be be the same ID as the ID during the foreach loop.

Currently, WHERE ID='$id' doesn't work.

Comment: You're also using the wrong connection variable in `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);` when it should be `$mysqli`

Comment: Thanks fred, new to the whole php thing. Will update to mysqli right away.

I'm using the loop to list my database, I'm not sure what you mean by what I'm using one in the first place?

Comment: Scratch my comment about that. Change the variable and try it again, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by variable.

I've tried changing it to:

$sql="UPDATE testtable SET hitcount='$hitcount' WHERE id='2'";

where there is actually a number for id and it works 100%. However, I need it to be dynamic so that it will automatically place the row ID without me manually putting in the #.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you below, which worked for me. You will have to modify it in order to add the table tags that were not shown in your code, so I didn't know where to put them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me. You can modify it as per required.

What needed to be done was to pass an additional GET parameter for the related "id" in the URL, then pass that variable for it in the `WHERE` clause.

A header was also added in order to automatically redirect once a related URL to the given row has been clicked and show the results and to prevent the following warning:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...

***Sidenote:*** Read the comments left in the code below for additional information.

```
<?php 
ob_start(); // keep this, it's for the header

$DB_HOST = 'xxx'; // Replace
$DB_USER = 'xxx'; // with
$DB_PASS = 'xxx'; // your
$DB_NAME = 'xxx'; // own

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}

// Your original query. You can replace it if needed.
// $result = mysqli_query($Link,"SELECT * FROM testtable ".$orderbyfilter);

$result = mysqli_query($Link,"SELECT * FROM testtable");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr id='entry'><td>";
    echo "ID: " . $row['id'];

    $var = $row['id']; // used for the URL

    echo "<br>";

    echo $row['hitcount'];
    echo ucwords($row['name']);
    echo "</td><td align='center'>";
    echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">url</a>';
    echo " Add hit: ";
    echo "<a href='?action=callfunction&id=$var'>Click</a> ";

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'callfunction'){

// Used for the query and escape the URL
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($Link, $_GET['id']); 

$sql="UPDATE testtable SET hitcount = hitcount +1 WHERE id='".$var."'"; 

$result=mysqli_query($Link,$sql); 

// Added a header, otherwise the old method will generate the following warning
// Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...
header("Location: http://www.example.com/your_counter_file.php");
exit; // Keep this in order to stop further execution

// ^ Change the url in header above to reflect your Web site's address

    } // Closing brace for isset

    echo "</td><td align='center'>";
    echo $row['level'];
    echo "</td><td align='center'>";
    echo $row['hitcount'];
    echo "</td></tr>";

} // Closing brace for while loop

    mysqli_close($Link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query like this to update the counter

```
$sql="UPDATE testtable SET `hitcount`=hitcount+1 WHERE id=".$id;
```

Don't use single quotes around value of counter since its a `integer`

Comment: Thanks for your input on the syntax, will update it.

It still doesn't work. All the links update the entire table's hit counter.

Comment: no am using column name value and adding 1 to it, which is same as ` $hitcount = $row['hitcount'] + 1;` but in mysql